# Difference between (Diferença entre) logotipo, logomarca, logo e marca

Tags: uso-de-palavras, diferenças

These four words have meanings that are usually confused with each other or even used as synonyms. One of them is said that doesn't even exist and that is nothing more than a mistake.

"Logotipo" and "logo" are synonyms? And "marca" and "logomarca"?

---

Essas quatro palavras têm significados geralmente confundidos ou até mesmo usados como sinônimos. Uma delas é dito que não existe e que não passa de um equívoco.

Logotipo e logo são a mesma coisa? E marca e logomarca?

Comment: Logotipo, logo e logomarca são sinônimos. Marca é mais amplo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Logotipo e logo

"Logótipo" ou "logotipo" (leia a nota abaixo) e "logo" [são a mesma coisa](http://duvidas.dicio.com.br/logotipo-ou-logotipo#palavras_relacionadas), sendo "logo" nada mais do que a abreviação.

### Logomarca

"Logomarca" só aparece uma vez no corpus "CRPC Portugal only" e nenhuma no CETEMPúblico, enquanto que no [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/x.asp) ela aparece seis vezes, todas de origem brasileira, e é notável que essa palavra é mais conhecida pelos brasileiros do que pelos portugueses, ou até mesmo inexistente, como é [dito pelo Artefacto](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1112/difference-between-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-logotipo-logomarca-logo-e-marca#comment-2888) abaixo.

Pelos usos e pela [definição no dicionário](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/logomarca), parece ser exatamente o mesmo que logotipo. Porém, essa palavra já foi assunto pra [muita discussão](http://chocoladesign.com/logo-logotipo-ou-logomarca-batalha-final) se [seria correto](http://webinsider.com.br/2009/02/12/e-correto-dizer-logomarca-nao-seria-logotipo/) ou [não](https://speakindesign.wordpress.com/2011/03/28/o-uso-incorreto-de-palavras-usadas-por-varios-design/) o uso dela. Já outros [consideram essa discussão vã](http://designpravida.blogspot.com.br/2009/02/logomarca-e-discussao-vazia.html), que de fato o é, até porque a palavra é oficialmente reconhecida pela Academia Brasileira de Letras, e segundo as definições dos dicionários, são praticamente a mesma coisa, apesar de não os terem como sinônimos, e seu uso ser no mínimo desencorajado por muitos.

### Marca

Já "marca" dificilmente se refere exclusivamente ao logótipo, e na verdade é um termo que inclui nome, logótipo e outras coisas que os consumidores associam a determinados produtos. Corresponde mais ao inglês *brand*.

---

**Nota:** "Logotipo" é a forma mais usada na oralidade, porém "logótipo" é considerado o mais correto, embora incomum, como é explicado [neste artigo](http://duvidas.dicio.com.br/logotipo-ou-logotipo/).

Comment: @BrunoLopes Como por exemplo?

Comment: Bom, poderia explicando o motivo de logomarca ser considerado redundante, baseando-se no original grego, e toda a discussão que existe sobre se logomarca é incorreta ou não, como é explicado em detalhes [aqui](https://speakindesign.wordpress.com/2011/03/28/o-uso-incorreto-de-palavras-usadas-por-varios-design/), apesar de ser oficialmente reconhecida.

Comment: @BrunoLopes Podia, mas "logomarca" é virtualmente inexistente em Portugal e eu nunca ouvira tal palavra. Parece-me que estás em melhor posição para responder à tua própria pergunta, o que é perfeitamente legítimo pelas regras do site.

Comment: Mas não precisa se limitar apenas a Portugal, no Brasil é comum ela ser usada. Eu não respondi para dar oportunidade para outros responderem.

Comment: @BrunoLopes Marquei-a como community wiki.